# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type on a linkedlist

Tags: c

I get an error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" and i don't know why.
i saw others many post but i didn't finde the error so please help me :)
here is my struct:

```
typedef struct _linkedList{
    int info;
    int cont;
    struct _linkedlist* next;
    struct _linkedList* prew;
} linkedList;
```

and this is the position where i get the error:

```
linkedList* p;
int pos = 0;
while(pre->prew->cont < pre->cont && pre->prew != NULL){
     p = pre->prew;
     if(p->prew != *head){
          p->prew->next = pre;
          pre->prew = p->prew;
          p->next = pre->next;
          p->prew = pre;
          pre->next->prew = p; //error
          pre->next = p;
          pos++;
     }else{
          p->next = pre->next;
          pre->next->prew = p; //error
          pre->next = p;
          p->prew = pre;
          *head = pre;
     }
}
```

where the variable "pre" is the head of the list. and why the compiler dont give me an error in :

```
p->prew->next = pre;
```

thanks :)

Comment: You have a typo - lower case 'L' in `_linkedlist` in declaration of `next`.

Comment: also, it's `prev`, not `prew`...

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the struct name for `next`, there it says `_linkedlist` instead of `_linkedList`:

```
struct _linkedlist* next;
struct _linkedList* prew;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the definition of the struct and actual function in different files?  Generally this error means that the compiler does not know what the type of the pointer is that you are defrefencing.